# editing swfobject.js code so hyperlinks inside the flash widget open in a new window

Tags: javascript, flash, hyperlink, swfobject

I have a flash calendar widget (code shown directly below) and I do not have access to anything other than the compiled .swf file (no access to .fla).

The widget contains some hyperlinks to other websites, these links are dynamic and changes based on a number of things.

There is also a corresponding swfobject.js file that is used to add functionality to the flash widget. The swfobject.js code is shown further down this post.

Currently, the way the code is now, when I click any of the hyperlinks that are available to me in the widget, the destination website that hyperlink takes me to opens in THE SAME PAGE as the flash widget which is a big problem.

I need to edit the code below so that any hyperlinks that are clicked inside of the flash widget open in a brand new browser window and do not take the user away from the original widget other than opening a new page with new content.

Because the hyperlinks that are available are always changing, the swfobject code below uses some functions and parameters.

I am hoping you can show me exactly what code I must insert, and exactly where I must insert it, in order to alter the behavior that happens so that when a user clicks one of the hyperlinks inside the flash widget, so that the content at the other end of the hyperlink opens in a new window, instead of opening in the same window.

See code below. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

**Flash Widget Code**

```
<!-- Embedded Calendar -->
  <div id="activecontent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="awccalendar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("awc.swf", "awccalendar2", "700", "180", "8", "#ffffff");
so.addVariable('calendarid', '0');
so.addVariable('appurl', '');
// Flash Widget Initial Date should be ddmmyyyy
so.addVariable('ldate', '20052014');
so.write('awccalendar');
</script>
</div>

  <!-- Embedded Calendar -->
```

**SWFOBJECT.JS CODE**

```
/** * SWFObject v1.5: Flash Player detection and embed - http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/ * * SWFObject is (c) 2007 Geoff Stearns and is released under the MIT License: * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php * */ if(typeof deconcept=="undefined"){var deconcept=new Object();}if(typeof deconcept.util=="undefined"){deconcept.util=new Object();}if(typeof deconcept.SWFObjectUtil=="undefined"){deconcept.SWFObjectUtil=new Object();}deconcept.SWFObject=function(_1,id,w,h,_5,c,_7,_8,_9,_a){if(!document.getElementById){return;}this.DETECT_KEY=_a?_a:"detectflash";this.skipDetect=deconcept.util.getRequestParameter(this.DETECT_KEY);this.params=new Object();this.variables=new Object();this.attributes=new Array();if(_1){this.setAttribute("swf",_1);}if(id){this.setAttribute("id",id);}if(w){this.setAttribute("width",w);}if(h){this.setAttribute("height",h);}if(_5){this.setAttribute("version",new deconcept.PlayerVersion(_5.toString().split(".")));}this.installedVer=deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.getPlayerVersion();if(!window.opera&&document.all&&this.installedVer.major>7){deconcept.SWFObject.doPrepUnload=true;}if(c){this.addParam("bgcolor",c);}var q=_7?_7:"high";this.addParam("quality",q);this.setAttribute("useExpressInstall",false);this.setAttribute("doExpressInstall",false);var _c=(_8)?_8:window.location;this.setAttribute("xiRedirectUrl",_c);this.setAttribute("redirectUrl","");if(_9){this.setAttribute("redirectUrl",_9);}};deconcept.SWFObject.prototype={useExpressInstall:function(_d){this.xiSWFPath=!_d?"expressinstall.swf":_d;this.setAttribute("useExpressInstall",true);},setAttribute:function(_e,_f){this.attributes[_e]=_f;},getAttribute:function(_10){return this.attributes[_10];},addParam:function(_11,_12){this.params[_11]=_12;},getParams:function(){return this.params;},addVariable:function(_13,_14){this.variables[_13]=_14;},getVariable:function(_15){return this.variables[_15];},getVariables:function(){return this.variables;},getVariablePairs:function(){var _16=new Array();var key;var _18=this.getVariables();for(key in _18){_16[_16.length]=key+"="+_18[key];}return _16;},getSWFHTML:function(){var _19="";if(navigator.plugins&&navigator.mimeTypes&&navigator.mimeTypes.length){if(this.getAttribute("doExpressInstall")){this.addVariable("MMplayerType","PlugIn");this.setAttribute("swf",this.xiSWFPath);}_19="<embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" src=\""+this.getAttribute("swf")+"\" width=\""+this.getAttribute("width")+"\" height=\""+this.getAttribute("height")+"\" style=\""+this.getAttribute("style")+"\"";_19+=" id=\""+this.getAttribute("id")+"\" name=\""+this.getAttribute("id")+"\" ";var _1a=this.getParams();for(var key in _1a){_19+=[key]+"=\""+_1a[key]+"\" ";}var _1c=this.getVariablePairs().join("&");if(_1c.length>0){_19+="flashvars=\""+_1c+"\"";}_19+="/>";}else{if(this.getAttribute("doExpressInstall")){this.addVariable("MMplayerType","ActiveX");this.setAttribute("swf",this.xiSWFPath);}_19="<object id=\""+this.getAttribute("id")+"\" classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\" width=\""+this.getAttribute("width")+"\" height=\""+this.getAttribute("height")+"\" style=\""+this.getAttribute("style")+"\">";_19+="<param name=\"movie\" value=\""+this.getAttribute("swf")+"\" />";var _1d=this.getParams();for(var key in _1d){_19+="<param name=\""+key+"\" value=\""+_1d[key]+"\" />";}var _1f=this.getVariablePairs().join("&");if(_1f.length>0){_19+="<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\""+_1f+"\" />";}_19+="</object>";}return _19;},write:function(_20){if(this.getAttribute("useExpressInstall")){var _21=new deconcept.PlayerVersion([6,0,65]);if(this.installedVer.versionIsValid(_21)&&!this.installedVer.versionIsValid(this.getAttribute("version"))){this.setAttribute("doExpressInstall",true);this.addVariable("MMredirectURL",escape(this.getAttribute("xiRedirectUrl")));document.title=document.title.slice(0,47)+" - Flash Player Installation";this.addVariable("MMdoctitle",document.title);}}if(this.skipDetect||this.getAttribute("doExpressInstall")||this.installedVer.versionIsValid(this.getAttribute("version"))){var n=(typeof _20=="string")?document.getElementById(_20):_20;n.innerHTML=this.getSWFHTML();return true;}else{if(this.getAttribute("redirectUrl")!=""){document.location.replace(this.getAttribute("redirectUrl"));}}return false;}};deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.getPlayerVersion=function(){var _23=new deconcept.PlayerVersion([0,0,0]);if(navigator.plugins&&navigator.mimeTypes.length){var x=navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"];if(x&&x.description){_23=new deconcept.PlayerVersion(x.description.replace(/([a-zA-Z]|\s)+/,"").replace(/(\s+r|\s+b[0-9]+)/,".").split("."));}}else{if(navigator.userAgent&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows CE")>=0){var axo=1;var _26=3;while(axo){try{_26++;axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash."+_26);_23=new deconcept.PlayerVersion([_26,0,0]);}catch(e){axo=null;}}}else{try{var axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7");}catch(e){try{var axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6");_23=new deconcept.PlayerVersion([6,0,21]);axo.AllowScriptAccess="always";}catch(e){if(_23.major==6){return _23;}}try{axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");}catch(e){}}if(axo!=null){_23=new deconcept.PlayerVersion(axo.GetVariable("$version").split(" ")[1].split(","));}}}return _23;};deconcept.PlayerVersion=function(_29){this.major=_29[0]!=null?parseInt(_29[0]):0;this.minor=_29[1]!=null?parseInt(_29[1]):0;this.rev=_29[2]!=null?parseInt(_29[2]):0;};deconcept.PlayerVersion.prototype.versionIsValid=function(fv){if(this.major<fv.major){return false;}if(this.major>fv.major){return true;}if(this.minor<fv.minor){return false;}if(this.minor>fv.minor){return true;}if(this.rev<fv.rev){return false;}return true;};deconcept.util={getRequestParameter:function(_2b){var q=document.location.search||document.location.hash;if(_2b==null){return q;}if(q){var _2d=q.substring(1).split("&");for(var i=0;i<_2d.length;i++){if(_2d[i].substring(0,_2d[i].indexOf("="))==_2b){return _2d[i].substring((_2d[i].indexOf("=")+1));}}}return "";}};deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.cleanupSWFs=function(){var _2f=document.getElementsByTagName("OBJECT");for(var i=_2f.length-1;i>=0;i--){_2f[i].style.display="none";for(var x in _2f[i]){if(typeof _2f[i][x]=="function"){_2f[i][x]=function(){};}}}};if(deconcept.SWFObject.doPrepUnload){if(!deconcept.unloadSet){deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.prepUnload=function(){__flash_unloadHandler=function(){};__flash_savedUnloadHandler=function(){};window.attachEvent("onunload",deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.cleanupSWFs);};window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload",deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.prepUnload);deconcept.unloadSet=true;}}if(!document.getElementById&&document.all){document.getElementById=function(id){return document.all[id];};}var getQueryParamValue=deconcept.util.getRequestParameter;var FlashObject=deconcept.SWFObject;var SWFObject=deconcept.SWFObject;
```

I am pretty sure there is some simple code addition I must make to the swfobjects.js file or into the widget code – similar to the code shown below. I just need some help from you on where exactly I must place the openLinksInNewWindow parameter so that it works.

**SAMPLE CODE I GRABBED FROM THE INTERNET THAT LOOKS SIMILAR TO THE CODE I HAVE**
**THIS SAMPLE CODE BELOW CONTAINS THE PARAMETER I NEED TO SOME HOW INCORPORATE INTO MY CODE**
**** SEE LINE 4 openLinksInNewWindow PARAMETER --** **THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SOMEHOW FIT BACK INTO THE CODE THAT I HAVE ABOVE ****

```
1.  <script type="text/javascript">
2.      swfobject.embedSWF("http://tagul.com/cdn/cloudTest.swf", "myCloud",
3.          "600", "600", "10.0.0", "http://cdn.tagul.com/expressInstall.swf",
4.          {id: "demo@demo", openLinksInNewWindow: "true"},
5.          {allowscriptaccess: "always", bgcolor: "#ffffff"},
6.          {id: "myCloudObject", name: "myCloudObject"});
7.         </script>
```

Comment: Under same situation ? Any solution?