# How to open link button inside flash content in new window

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, hyperlink, swfobject

Same as [editing swfobject.js code so hyperlinks inside the flash widget open in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782954/editing-swfobject-js-code-so-hyperlinks-inside-the-flash-widget-open-in-a-new-wi) (but no response)

I have flash content with hyperlinks inside the content. The links are opening in new Tab in all browsers except IE. In IE its opening as POP-UP . So client is requesting to fix it.

The flash content is loaded from Tridion CMS.

```
 {
  var so = new SWFObject('/TridionMultimedia/wired-process_tcm24-2197.swf', 'wiredprocess', '680', '244', '8', '#ffffff');
  so.useExpressInstall("/swf/expressinstall.swf");
  so.addParam("quality", "high");
  so.addParam('wmode', 'transparent');
  so1.addParam('openLinksInNewWindow', 'true');//tried but not working 
  so.write('divtcm24-484-64tcm:24-783-32');

  }
  else
  {
  var so1 = new SWFObject('/TridionMultimedia/COSVideoWidgetRotating_tcm24-191.swf', 'mymovie', '680', '244', '6', '#FFFFFF');
  so1.addParam("quality", "high");
  so1.addParam('wmode', 'opaque');
  so1.addParam('openLinksInNewWindow', 'true');//tried but not working 
  so1.write('divtcm24-484-64tcm:24-783-32');

  }
```

In the below website i saw the some code as 
https://tagul.com/forums/topic/forcing-links-to-open-in-a-new-window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("http://tagul.com/cdn/cloudTest.swf", "myCloud",
    "600", "600", "10.0.0", "http://cdn.tagul.com/expressInstall.swf",
    {id: "demo@demo", openLinksInNewWindow: "true"},
    {allowscriptaccess: "always", bgcolor: "#ffffff"},
    {id: "myCloudObject", name: "myCloudObject"});
```

But not sure how to add in my script . Or is this something related to browser property.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

When a link is clicked, you could refer to a function that runs this code:

```
var pageURL:String = ExternalInterface.call('YOUR_LINK');
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(pageURL), "_blank");
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SWF click event URL using [javascript + ExternalInterface] and call a window.open by yourself.

Check this link:

[Using the ExternalInterface Class to Bridge JavaScript and Flash](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/01/14/using-the-externalinterface-class-to-bridge-javascript-and-flash/)

Comment: Consider making your answer more valuable by including an example - instead of a link that may or not exist for future visitors.  Link only answers are considered bad practice on StackOverflow.

Comment: @LDMS Please note I added the code above and just for reference i added the link .